# prestashop how change some variable?

Tags: prestashop

I downloaded prestashop yesterday and now I want to make some changes. footer.tpl

```
<div id="right_column" class="column grid_2 omega">
    {$HOOK_RIGHT_COLUMN}
</div>
```

Is it possible to change `$HOOK_RIGHT_COLUMN`?

Comment: may it help http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/201709-hook-right-column/

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I just want to add more columns, sliders ect but I have no idea how to do that..Must I make a new modules if I want to do that?

Comment: Yes, the best way is to make modules hooked on the right column.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can check in v1.6.1.24, FrontController.php line 582

```
'HOOK_RIGHT_COLUMN' => ($this->display_column_right ? Hook::exec('displayRightColumn', array('cart' => $this->context->cart)) : ''),
```

So in case you need more columns, you make one (or more) extra, create the respective hooks in the table hook and create modules that hook to this custom hook.